# Location of ViewFields tag in GetListItems method + sharepoint web-services

Tags: xml, web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I want to retrieve data for all the columns and rows of a sharepoint list. So, i was trying to send a 'ViewFields' parameter specifying all the fields to be retrieved to the web-service function getListItems(). The request xml is as follows:

```
<GetListItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">  
              <listName>'.$list.'</listName> 

              <rowLimit>'.$limit.'</rowLimit>

              <queryOptions xmlns:SOAPSDK9="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" > 
                  <QueryOptions/> 
              </queryOptions> 
</GetListItems>
```

The 'ViewFields' tag is as follows:

```
<ViewFields>
   <FieldRef Name="ID" />
   <FieldRef Name="Title" />...
</ViewFields>
```

I tried to insert , but it is not overridding the fields in the default view. So, i thought may be i am not giving it in right place. So my question is Where should  tag come in the request xml such that it overriddes fields from default view. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Specify the specific view you want to use

Answer (score 0):

```
<GetListItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">  
       <listName>...</listName>  
       <viewName>....</viewName>  
      <Query> 
           <Where> 
               .
               .
            </Where> 
       </Query> 
      <ViewFields>
          <FieldRef Name="ID" /> 
          .
          .
          .
      </ViewFields> 
      <rowLimit>...</rowLimit> 
      <queryOptions xmlns:SOAPSDK9="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" > 
          <QueryOptions/> 
      </queryOptions> 
</GetListItems>
```